# I have kubuntu and ubuntu and they both show up as ubuntu on grub. What can i do?

Tags: boot, grub2

What can i do to fix this problem? How do I change the name of them on grub?

Comment: How to: Create a Customized GRUB2 Screen that is Maintenance Free.- Cavsfan
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MaintenanceFreeCustomGrub2Screen &
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/CustomMenus I am not a particular fan of Grub Customizer as it adds its own versions on grub's script files. But can make simple changes easy. https://answers.launchpad.net/grub-customizer/+faq/1355

Comment: It is often possible to identify the different installed systems by the other information in the grub menu, for example about the partition or the version number. But if you want to make it easy to tell the difference, I say '+1' to the links in @oldfred 's comment.

Comment: Another way is to edit the grub configuration file. `sudo nano -B /etc/default/grub`
Change GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR to whatever you want:
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="Kubuntu" 
`sudo update-grub`

Comment: @oldfred won't the `GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR` value change with the next kernel update or at the time of the next point release?